# how to add a path to symfony form's action attribute

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a method that creates a form like this:

```
class search {

  public function index() {} 

  public function createSearch() {

  $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null)
   ->add(...)
   ->add('search', SubmitType::class, ['attr' => 'action' => 'http://foo.bar/tar'])->getForm();

   return $this->render(...); 
 }

}
```

As you can see I want the `createSearch` to create a form that will submit into url 'http://foo.bar/tar' but when submit the form it does not go to that page

Answer (score 3):

You are adding an `action` attribute to your submit button, it is supposed to go with your `form` tag.

Form builder has a `setAction` method.

```
$this->createFormBuilder(null)
  ->setAction('http://foo.bar/tar')
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html